# How to disable immediate autocomplete in SQL Assistant for SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, autocomplete, ssms, code-assist

It's a bit annoying that SQL Assistant shows "autocomplete" window on each `,` or `.` button press.

Actually I don't need it's *assistance* in most of cases but still would like to have it's features enabled. So I don't want to switch it off (*suspend*), but'd like it to show me autocomplete window only when `CTRL+Space` pressed or with some delay.

I tryed to modify some options on "DB Options" tab for Sql Server, but they don't seem to make any effect on code completion/intellisence behaviour:

[image: options]

"Intellisense" options were "yes", after switch to "no" I did not mention any difference at all (while enabling "Ignore comments" did make effect).

Is there any option in SQL Assistant that does not totally disable it but makes it show me code-completion/snippet and any other windows only when I press `CTRL+Space` or after some delay?

`version 7.0.158 EE`

Comment: I believe, when you are typing and have a pop-up you can continue to type with ignoring the popup. Have you tried SSMSTollpack or Redgate prompt?

Comment: Stuff is required at job place (formatting and so on). To continue typing I have to press `Esc` hundreds of times because pressing any arrow  switches focus to popup window, `space` - selects first item from popup window...

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. I've never had to press `Esc` while typing.

Comment: I tried to disable Auto complete in SSMS 2016 and it does not work, However it works in SSMS 2014. Anyway, watch the video on how to do it the right way: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9QCKuGJE2E)